# Send commands to subprocess.Popen() process

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, subprocess, popen

I need to pass commands to a process on `subprocess.Popen()` but when I do, it only works if I use `stdin.close()` afterwards. My code is below.

```
sprocess.stdin.write('/stop'.encode())
sprocess.stdin.flush()
sprocess.stdin.close()
sprocess.stdout.close()
```

Works, but that is because of `stdin.close()` and I need to be able to do this without closing the pipes.

How can I pass commands to the process without closing the pipes after?

Comment: Note that `sprocess.stdin.write('/stop'.encode())` will not add a newline! Your subprocess is probably expecting a *line* of input, signified by either a newline or EOF. Closing `stdin` will send that EOF. Try sending `sprocess.stdin.write('/stop\n'.encode())` instead.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Could you please make that an answer is I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `sprocess.stdin.write('/stop'.encode())` will not add a newline! Your subprocess is probably expecting a *line* of input, signified by either a newline or EOF. Closing `stdin` will send that EOF.

Try sending `sprocess.stdin.write('/stop\n'.encode())` instead.